# useStarRating() hook returning 0 even after interacting with the star component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm using a custom useStarRating hook to manage the state of a star rating component in my React project. The hook seems to be working fine, but I'm having trouble getting the latest value of currentValue after the user interacts with the star component.

Even after clicking on a star, currentValue always returns 0 in the parent component. I've tried logging the value of currentValue in the parent component and in the Star component, but it always shows 0.

Here's the code for my `AddReviews` component:

```js
// AddReviews.js
import Star from './Star';
import useStarRating from '@/hooks/useStarRating';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';

const AddReviews = () => {
  const { currentValue } = useStarRating();
  const [reviewText, setReviewText] = useState('');

  const handleReviewTextChange = (event) => {
    setReviewText(event.target.value);
  };

  console.log('currentValue:', currentValue);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post('http://localhost:8080/review/2/user', {
        rating: currentValue,
        reviewText: reviewText,
      })
      .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p className="text-xl">Add Review</p>
      <div>
        <form className="flex flex-col" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Star />
          <textarea
            className="border border-gray-400 rounded-lg p-2"
            value={reviewText}
            onChange={handleReviewTextChange}
          ></textarea>
          <button className="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-2 rounded-lg mt-2 ">
            Post Review
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddReviews;
```

And here's the code for my `Star` component:

```
// Star.js
import { faStar } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Star = () => {
  const stars = Array(5).fill(0);
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(0);
  const [hoverValue, setHoverValue] = useState();

  const handleClick = (value) => {
    setCurrentValue(value);
  };

  const handelMouseHover = (value) => {
    setHoverValue(value);
  };

  const handelMouseLeave = () => {
    setHoverValue(undefined);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="cursor-pointer my-3">
        {stars.map((_, index) => {
          return (
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              key={index}
              icon={faStar}
              size="xl"
              color={
                (hoverValue || currentValue) > index ? '#FFD700' : '#A9A9A9'
              }
              onClick={() => handleClick(index + 1)}
              onMouseOver={() => handelMouseHover(index + 1)}
              onMouseLeave={handelMouseLeave}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Star;
```

here is code for my hook `useStarRating`

```
import { faStar } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { useState } from 'react';

const useStarRating = () => {
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(undefined);
  const [hoverValue, setHoverValue] = useState(undefined);

  const handleStarClick = (value) => {
    setCurrentValue(value);
    console.log("value");
    console.log(currentValue);
  };

  const handleStarHover = (value) => {
    setHoverValue(value);
  };

  const handleStarLeave = () => {
    setHoverValue(undefined);
  };

  return {
    currentValue,
    hoverValue,
    handleStarClick,
    handleStarHover,
    handleStarLeave,
  };
};

export default useStarRating;
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code in `Star.js`? It looks like it cuts off above.

Comment: Your star component returns an empty div. Can you show code where you actually render the starts and attach the handlers?

Comment: You are not using your hooks in Star.js. You need to import the hooks from your custom hook definition and use those inside of the handlers in Star.js

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that your hooks don't have / are global state.

The hook inside your `AddReviews` component is a new instance of the `useStarRating`. This creates a new state for the `hoverValue` and `currentValue`.

One way you might solve this is by passing the needed values and function down with the props. Your `Star` component will look something like this.

```js
const Star = ({ hoverValue, currentValue, setCurrentValue, setHoverValue }) => {
  const stars = Array(5).fill(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="cursor-pointer my-3">
        {stars.map((_, index) => {
          return (
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              key={index}
              icon={faStar}
              size="xl"
              color={
                (hoverValue || currentValue) > index ? "#FFD700" : "#A9A9A9"
              }
              onClick={() => setCurrentValue(index + 1)}
              onMouseOver={() => setHoverValue(index + 1)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setHoverValue(undefined)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now in your `AddReviews` component you can pass down the needed values.

```js
const AddReviews = () => {
  const { currentValue, setCurrentValue, hoverValue, setHoverValue } =
    useStarRating();
  const [reviewText, setReviewText] = useState("");

  // ...

  return (
    // ...
    <Star
      currentValue={currentValue}
      setCurrentValue={setCurrentValue}
      hoverValue={hoverValue}
      setHoverValue={setHoverValue}
    />
    // ...
  );
};
```

Another way you could solve this is by using [React context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context).

```js
const StarRatingContext = createContext({});

function StarRatingProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(undefined);
  const [hoverValue, setHoverValue] = useState(undefined);

  const handleStarClick = (value) => {
    setCurrentValue(value);
    console.log("value");
    console.log(currentValue);
  };

  const handleStarHover = (value) => {
    setHoverValue(value);
  };

  const handleStarLeave = () => {
    setHoverValue(undefined);
  };

  return {
    currentValue,
    hoverValue,
    handleStarClick,
    handleStarHover,
    handleStarLeave,
  };

  return <StarRatingContext.Provider>{children}</StarRatingContext.Provider>;
}

const useStarRating = () => useContext(StarRatingContext);
```

Wrap you `AddReviews` component in the `StarRatingProvider` and you will have your data in both components.